# Where do gedit's preferences get saved to?

Tags: windows, linux, gedit

I am using Gedit 2.28.3

From the filesystem, I would like to stop the program from showing the "There is a new version of gedit (x.x.x)"

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well, this is not really a programming question, but I will try to give a somewhat programming-related answer...*

The most accurate documentation of a piece of software is its source code; I downloaded the source code for your version of `gedit` from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnome.org/sources/gedit/2.28/) and did a search for the string "There is a new version". I got a hit in `plugins/checkupdate/gedit-check-update-plugin.c`.

It is reasonable to assume that this functionality is provided in a modular manner through a plugin - one that at least my Linux distribution disables explicitly with the `--disable-updater` `configure` option when compiling. Since it's a plugin, the easiest way to deal with this would be via the `Edit->Preferences->Plugins` tab.

If you want to disable the plugin without going through the `gedit` user interface, you can try using the `gconf-editor` tool to modify the GConf settings directly. Just navigate to `apps/gedit-2/plugins` and remove the `checkupdate` plugin from the list.

If you do not want to use a graphical utility, you *might* be a ble to modify the underlying `GConf` file directly - mine is at `~/.gconf/apps/gedit-2/plugins/%gconf.xml`. It's an XML file and the format is self-evident...

*Disclaimer: modifying GConf files directly is not recommended - you're on your own...*

PS: Oh, removing the plugin file, `libcheckupdate.so` or something similar, *might* also work - or it might set your house on fire...